# openGL drawing GL_LINES giving incorrect result

Tags: opengl, vertex-buffer, vertex-array-object, openglrenderer

I am trying to draw a grid of velocity vectors, I expect the velocity at each grid point to be a line with a slop of 1. A slanting line, but I always end up with a vertical line. I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong. Is there something I'm overlooking?

Here is how my vertex buffer looks :

```
float vel_pos[6*(N+2)*(N+2)];
int index1 = 0;
for (int i=0;i<N+2;i++)
{
    for (int j=0;j<N+2;j++)
    {
        vel_pos[index1] = float(i);
        vel_pos[index1+1] = float(j);
        vel_pos[index1+2] = 0.0f;
        vel_pos[index1+3] = float(i) +0.5f;
        vel_pos[index1+4] = float(j) + 0.5f;
        vel_pos[index1+5] = 0.0f;
        index1 += 6;
    }
}
```

Here is how I am creating my VBO and VAO :

```
unsigned int VBO, VAO;
glGenVertexArrays(1, &VAO);
glGenBuffers(1, &VBO);

// Bind vertex array object first and then bind the vertex buffer objects
glBindVertexArray(VAO);

glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, VBO);

glBufferData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, sizeof(vel_pos), vel_pos, GL_STREAM_DRAW);


GLint velAttrib = glGetAttribLocation(ourShader.ID, "aPos");

// iterpreting data from buffer 
glVertexAttribPointer(velAttrib, 3, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE,  6 * sizeof(float), (void*)0);
glEnableVertexAttribArray(0);
```

Here is my vertex shader :

```
  out vec4 vertexColor;
  layout (location = 0) in vec3 aPos; 
  layout (location = 1) in float densitySource; /* source of density */
  uniform mat4 transform;
  uniform mat4 projection;

  void main()
  {
  gl_Position = projection*transform * vec4(aPos, 1.0);
  vertexColor = vec4(1, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0);
  }
```

And here's my drawing code :

```
  ourShader.use();

    glm::mat4 trans = glm::mat4(1.0f);
    trans = glm::translate(trans, glm::vec3(-0.5f, -0.5f, 0.0f));
    unsigned int transformMatrixLocation = glGetUniformLocation(ourShader.ID, "transform");
    glUniformMatrix4fv(transformMatrixLocation, 1, GL_FALSE, glm::value_ptr(trans));

    glm::mat4 projection = glm::ortho(-10.0f, 110.0f, -1.0f, 110.0f, -1.0f, 100.0f);

    unsigned int projectionMatrixLocation = glGetUniformLocation(ourShader.ID, "projection");
    glUniformMatrix4fv(projectionMatrixLocation, 1, GL_FALSE, glm::value_ptr(projection));

    glBindVertexArray(VAO); 
    glLineWidth(1.0f);
    glDrawArrays(GL_LINES,  0, (N+2)*(N+2));
```

This is the image I get :
[resulting image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8RqWT.png)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The 5th parameter (`stride`) of [`glVertexAttribPointer`](https://www.khronos.org/registry/OpenGL-Refpages/gl4/html/glVertexAttribPointer.xhtml) is the offset between two vertex coordinates and not between to primitives. Since your vertex coordinates have 3 components of type `float`, the offset has to be `3 * sizeof(float)`:

```
glVertexAttribPointer(velAttrib, 3, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE,  3 * sizeof(float), (void*)0);
```

Because you set an offset of `6 * sizeof(float)`, you have skipped every 2 coordinate and have drawn lines between the points of the grid.

But note, if `stride` is 0, the generic vertex attributes are understood to be tightly packed in the array. This is the case, so you ca use an offset of 0:

```
glVertexAttribPointer(velAttrib, 3, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE,  0, (void*)0);
```